# How to install portmaster on FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, bsd, bsd-ports

I'm trying to install portmaster on FreeBSD but I get an error about the port format:

```
root@freebsd:/usr/ports/ports-mgmt/portmaster # make install clean
===>  portmaster-3.17.8_1 pkg(8) must be version 1.6.0 or greater, but you
have 1.4.12. You must upgrade the ports-mgmt/pkg port first.
*** Error code 1

Stop.
make: stopped in /usr/ports/ports-mgmt/portmaster
```

How can I upgrade the port file to the latest version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Update your ports tree

   ```
   portsnap fetch update
   ```
2. Navigate to the `pkg` directory

   ```
   cd /usr/ports/ports-mgmt/pkg
   ```

   or

   ```
   cd /usr/ports/port-mgmt/pkg
   ```

   for older versions.
3. Build and install the `pkg` package

   ```
   make config-recursive install distclean
   ```